# How do i populate an Array in one class based on a textfield in another class?(Actionscript 3.0)

Tags: actionscript-3

i have a class (TheList.as). in which i have an array "Data" and it has a couple of values. Then i have a loop through which i am creating a scrollable list which uses the values from "Data" array.    [I am trying make a unit converter]

Then i have another class "Units.as". In that class i have created three instances of "TheList". A main list ("myList"), and to sublists "ListFrom" and "ListTo". They are using values from "Data" array. Now i have text field whose value changes to whatever item is clicked. When i click "Angle" in the main list, i want the sublists to get populated with ("Degree", "Radian" etc)..

Here is what i tried

```
if(myList._TextLabel.text == "Angle")
{
ListFrom.Data = ["Degree", "Radian"];
}
```

But nothing happens, i do not get any error either. When i do this in an "ENTER_FRAME" event and trace (ListFrom.Data), i can see that the values change, but they do not get assigned to the list items in the list. I would really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Here are complete Classes for understanding the situation better(the code is pretty messy, as i am a newbie to OOP)

TheList.as:   http://pastebin.com/FLy5QV9i
Units.as : http://pastebin.com/z2CcHZzC

Answer (score 0):

where you call ListFrom.Data = ["Degree","Radian"], make sure when the data changed, the renders in the ListFrom have been set new data. for example, you may use MyRender in ListFrom for show, you should debug in the set data method in MyRender.
you should call the code below after you call ListFrom.Data = ["Degree","Radian"];

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < Data.legnth;i++) {
    var render:MyRender = ListFrom[i] as MyRender;

    if (render) {
         render.data = Data[i];
    } else {
         var render:MyRender = new MyRender();
         render.data = Data[i];
         ListFrom.addChild(render);
    }
}
```

Comment: "MyRender" is not being recognized..I have updated the question. Could you please look at those classes and get a better idea of my situation. Thanks!

Comment: It's a problem that I can't open the two class website. MyRender is the class you use to show in the list, and a list is made up of serveral renders. For example, a render has a image, where the set data function called in the render, the render will set a url to the image.

Comment: In the function initialize of TheList, you shouldn't create a new ListContainer each time. Instead, you should create only once, and where you call the initialize function ,you should remove all the children of _Container, and when add the listItem,as i don't know how the listItem work, you may debug into listItem.value. And at last, where you have add all children, check the width and height of  _container.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event listeners, singleton classes or reference one class to another, depending on the style you want. All are equally valid and fast / efficient.